# Terraform throws Invalid Terraform AWS provider credentials error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to terraform and coding in general. I am trying to launch an EC2 instance in my AWS management console. When I do terraform plan, it throws this error:

Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid
│       status code: 403, request id: a387a4a4-af9b-45d3-b858-a92f3dbc7a6e

I have tried multiple solutions suggested by Chatgpt, including: Verifying AWS Credentials File, checking AM User Permissions and Status, clearing Clear Terraform Cache. but nothing is working. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since you have already verified AWS Credentials File and checked IAM User Permissions and Status, let's try below options:

1. Validate the profile parameter in terraform as well as `~/.aws/credentials` file if you are using one.
2. Unset any related environment variables: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`
3. Delete the `~/.aws/credentials` file and rerun `aws configure`.
4. Clear the Terraform cache as you already did: `rm -r .terraform .terraform.lock.hcl`
5. Now try to run `terraform plan` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I deleted the ~/.aws/credentials and reran aws configure. That worked!